# jquery loop function, reset style, loop again

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate, reset

What I'm trying to do is animate the "top" position of an html element, and then once the function has run, reset the style and start the loop over.

I'm certainly not a pro at this. I'm sure there's a better way to do it, and I've only been able to get this far by piecing together various "tutorials" I've found.

The element that I'm animating is contained in a  with overflow:hidden.

Here is the script that I've been able to get so far:

```
$(function(){
    function loop(n) {
    if(n > 0)
    {
      setTimeout(function(){
      $("#target").animate({'top': '-=44px' },"slow", loop(n-1));
      }, 3000);
    }
    }
    loop(15);
});
```

What I'd like is after this has run, I'd like it to reset the "top" property of the #target element, and then start over (infinitely).

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I realize I may be going about this wrong from the start, so any suggestions will be great!

Thanks!

Edit: Put together a jsFiddle to show what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/E7mTR/

Comment: So. what's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: Nothing. Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I'd like is for *after* this code has run, the style of the #target to be reset, and then this code to run again. And then repeat all of that over and over infinitely.

Comment: Just edited the orignal post to include a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7mTR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(function(){
            function loop(n) {
                if(n <= 0){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".wrapper ul").animate({'top': '0' },"fast", function(){
                            loop(15)
                        });
                    }, 300);
                }else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".wrapper ul").animate({'top': '-=44px' },"fast", function(){
                            loop(n-1)
                        });
                    }, 300);
                }
            }
            loop(15);
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9JyRf/)

The code can be cleanup using something like

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $ul = $(".wrapper ul");
    function animate(n, top) {
        $ul.delay(300).animate({'top': top },"fast", function(){
            loop(n-1)
        });
    }
    function loop(n){
        if(n <= 0) {
            animate(15, '0');
        } else {
            animate(n, '-=44px');
        }
    }
    loop(15)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9JyRf/3/)

Comment: This may be way outside the scope of the original question, but is there any way to dynamically set the number of times it loops based on how many <li> elements exist in the <ul>? This would help prevent the client from breaking things ;)

Comment: sure instead of hard coding 15, you can use `$ul.children().length` and see

Comment: Thanks so much, I seriously appreciate it. Can I donate you a few dollars for your help?